# Kusto result column name, bin value from request_parameters

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Using query_parameters, how can I:

1. specify a result column name (ex: `summarize ResultColumnName = count()`)
2. specify the `value` of a `bin`, when `value` is actually the name of a column in the table

This is easiest to summarize with an example:

```
let myTable = datatable (Timestamp:datetime)
    [datetime(1910-06-11),
     datetime(1930-01-01),
     datetime(1997-06-25),
     datetime(1997-06-25)];
let UntrustedUserInput_ColumnName = "MyCount"; // actually from query_parameters
let UntrustedUserInput_BinValue = "Timestamp"; // actually from query_parameters
let UntrustedUserInput_BinRoundTo = "365d";    // actually from query_parameters

// the query I really want to perform
myTable
| summarize MyCount=count() by bin(todatetime(Timestamp), totimespan(365d));

// what the query looks like if I use query_parameters
myTable
| summarize UntrustedUserInput_ColumnName=count() by bin(todatetime(UntrustedUserInput_BinValue), totimespan(UntrustedUserInput_BinRoundTo));
```

Results:

```
Timestamp               MyCount
---------               -------
1909-09-26T00:00:00Z    1
1929-09-21T00:00:00Z    1
1996-09-04T00:00:00Z    2

Column1     UntrustedUserInput_ColumnName
-------     -----------------------------
            4
```

I can't find a solution to #1.

It appears #2 can almost be solved by using `column_ifexists`, but I don't have a "default" to fall back on, I'd rather just fail if the column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Treating column names as variables is not possible since columns names are part of the result schema coming out of each operator (with the exception of the "evaluate" operator, see specifically the [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin).

Answer (score 1):

There actually **is** a way to set variable names to a column, using a hacky trick:

```
let VariableColumnName = "TestColumn"; // the new column name that you want
range i from 1 to 5 step 1             // this is just a sample query
| project pack(VariableColumnName, i)  // this created a JSON
| evaluate bag_unpack(Column1)         // unpacking the JSON creates a column with a dynamic name
```

This will return a column named `TestColumn`, which is set in `VariableColumnName`.